# JQuery hide parent element based on child

Tags: jquery

```
<li class="abc">
<div attribute="xyz">stuff</div>
</li>
```

If I have the above. I'd like to hide

```
<li class="abc">
```

tags and children tags if child

```
<div atribute="xyz">
```

exists.

Thank you.

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: I got this far:  $$("li:contains('div attribute='xyz''')").invoke("hide");

Comment: Just tried:  $$("li>div:contains('attribute')").invoke("hide");

Comment: `.invoke()` that's hilarious and the attribute `attribute` is pretty funny as well. Oh yeah the `$$` is great. is this jQuery version8419149/4212468jygvyjvcj?

Comment: @zer00ne its freestyle :D - no - acually its prototype :)

Comment: OIC, thanks @Pilan .  If there's ever a library called freestyle I'll avoid it like the plague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed jquery DOM, Please check it this and try.

```js
$(function(){
    $("div[someattribute='xyz']").parent().hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="abc">this needs to go away
       <div someattribute="xyz">hello</div>
    </li>
    <li>This doesn't either</li>
    <li>This does, but whatever.</li>
    <li>And I was like, "whatever dude".</li>
    <li>This doesn't have our text, once again</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: instead of `parent` you can use `closest('li')` in case div is wrapped by whatever

Comment: @Pilan, we can also use closest('li') it's mainly depends on requirements only

Comment: Still no.  I'm in a fiddle and even closest('li') isn't working

Comment: @mike, can you paste fiddle url, i will check it out.

Comment: @Mike, someattribute="xyz" is child of li, so, it has no siblings or, closest elements of li, so, closest won't work here, please go through the jquery documentation

Comment: updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92wo3f6r/18/). works fine for me :)

Comment: @Mike, please check updated answer, i think you have missed jquery plugin and DOM

Answer (score 1):

Here a prototype answer (maybe more related to your attempts)

```js
function doIt() {
  $$('[someattribute=xyz]').each(function(e){ e.up('li').hide(); });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.3/prototype.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="abc">this needs to go away
       <div someattribute="xyz">hello</div>
    </li>
    <li>This doesn't either</li>
    <li class="abc">this needs to go away aswell
       <div class="ohMyGodAWrapper">
         <div someattribute="xyz">hello</div>
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>This does, but whatever.</li>
    <li>And I was like, "whatever dude".</li>
    <li>This doesn't have our text, once again</li>
</ul>

<button id="go" onclick="javascript: doIt();">Click Me!</button>
```